# Composer Install for a PHP-C++ Project

Tags: php, composer-php

I've read several questions in SO about how to install 3rd party libraries in another "project". Inevitably, the answer is to use `composer` and they all say we need a composer.json file in the project root.

I'm confused. I am working on a project, whose "source" build has the following structure

```
web/
src/
```

The `web` folder includes several PHP files that are implemented by the project. This project so far **doesn't** use composer at all.

The `src` directory contains c/c++ files for some core engine files.

I now need to add, let's say, [php-jwt](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) to this "project" (which is a hybrid PHP+C++ project) in a way that I can include the jwt library in some file inside `web/views/myfile.php`

I also have the following additional requirements:

- The project is quite a large one, and its packaging rules are quite complex. At the end, basically RPM or DEB files are created that users install on their systems. I want to make sure users installing the project, of which `jwt-php` is a part don't need to install composer.

Given that, where exactly do I download the jwt library using composer? Inside `web/` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe, we just add a `composer.json` right next to these two directories:

```
- web/
- src/
- vendor/---------
composer.json    -
composer.lock    -
                 ------ autoload.php
                 ------ composer
                 ------ jwt-php
                 ------ other-php-cpp-package-1
                 ------ other-php-cpp-package-2
                 ------ other-php-cpp-package-3
                 ------ other-php-cpp-package-4
                 -------
```

Then, our `composer.json` might look like:

```
{
    "name": "project/cphp",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "PHP C++ Project X",
    "keywords": ["php","c++"],
    "copyright": "",
    "license": "",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "authors": [{
        "name": "user1361529",
        "role": "Developer"
    }],
    "require": {
        "jwt-php": "*",
    },
    "require-dev": {},
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [],
        "psr-0": {},
        "psr-4": {}
    },
    "config": {}
}
```

If we are using a MacOS for example, we would install the composer:

```
cd path/to/main/dir

sudo composer install
```

We can always change the directory later. It might not be so important initially.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, your project is a multi-language hybrid application.

I do not recommend that you install the vendor's vendor directory in the root directory of your project. If your php mainly exists in the web directory, then you can install the vendor in the `web` directory. The directory structure is as follows:

```
web/
---vendor/
------autoload.php
------...
---composer.json
---composer.lock
---...
src/
```

For references to installed libraries, you can use the `include '../vendor/autoload.php'` in `web/views/myfile.php` to load the composer auto-registration script (or you might be able to introduce autoload in a unified main entry script). Then call the third-party library through the namespace: `new Firebase\JWT\JWT();`

Then, submit the vendor to your VCS and package it into RPM or DEB so your customers don't need to install composer.

Answer by Google Translate

**Edit**:
It is dangerous to place the vendor directory in the directory with open permissions to the web server. Please adjust the specific directory structure according to the actual situation. By the way, the directory named web does not necessarily have the open permission of the web server.

Comment: Note that having `composer.json`, `composer.lock` and `vendor` inside of web-accessible directory is potential security issue.

Comment: Oh, ok. In that case I suppose then I need to do what @Emma suggested in the other answer. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

If you do not want to use composer then you can simply download the library and call it in your code.

```
<?php

  require _DIR.'path-to-librayr';

  use class;
```